# Eccentricity is invariant for ellipse defined by intersection between plane and ellipsoid [can't be correct]??

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

When a plane intersects a sphere, the intersection is always a circle, due to rotational symmetry etc.

However, if a plane intersects an ellipsoid( say, the rotation of $$(\frac{x}{a})^2+(\frac{y}{b})^2=1$$ about the x axis) it forms ellipses of different eccentricities. It makes sense that every plane parallel to the x-z plane intersects to form a circle.

Similarly, (i suspect that) all planes  parallel to the xy plane form an ellipse of eccentricity of $b/a$.

Are all eccentrities of a planar intersection with this ellipsoid bounded by these two values?

I took a look at a generic ellipsoid:

$$(\frac{x}{a})^2+(\frac{y}{b})^2+(\frac{z}{c})^2=1$$

and a general plane: $$fx+gy+hz=1$$.

At first, I tried something weird, but I just wanted to get a 2-variable expression for the answer, so I used substitution to get the solution set:

$$(\frac{x}{a})^2+(\frac{y}{b})^2+(\frac{1-fx-gy}{ch})^2=1$$

But then isn't the **definition** of eccentricity: c/a, or:

$$eccentricity^2=1-(\frac{b}{a})^2$$.

But then the eccentricity is invariant, when looking at the generic plane? This makes no sense to me, does anyone have any insights?
 Sorry, I have not done this type of math in a very long time.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following this, but realize the ellipse you create no longer has the x and y axes as its major and minor axes. The ellipse is now "tilted" and you need to rotate your x and y axes to find the major and minor ellipse axes and thus find the eccentricity.

Comment: Thats true, but that shouldnt actually affect the eccentricity. Im sure that something is wrong.

Comment: For a tilted ellipse, `a` and `b` only give you the x and y intercepts of the ellipse. These are no longer the end points of the major and minor axes of the ellipse.

Comment: Is that true? I thought that the formula generated is on a particular plane, and that the equation given for eccentricity would reasonably result in a given eccentricity

Comment: Why do you argue that the values $a,b$ are giving c,y intercepts? intercepts of what?

Answer (score 0):

Simply substituting the formula of the plane into that of the ellipse is not going to work as expected. Computing the eccentricity from a coordinate representation of an ellipse requires the underlying basis to be orthonormal. And while for most planes, each point can be described by $x$ and $y$ coordinate, with the $z$ coordinate implied by the equation of the plane, the projections of the $x$ and $y$ vector onto that plane are in general not orthonormal.

So I'd start by picking two orthogonal unit length vectors in the plane, and then expressing the ellipse with respect to these. Then you will see that the principal axes depend very much on the choice of plane.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer. What I was thinking of as a counterexample is the parametric plot of:

$
   \left\{\frac{4}{3} \sqrt{2} \cos (t),\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{2} \sin (t+45
    {}^{\circ})\right\}
$

which looks like this:

[image]

so the x and y intercepts are not the lengths of the major and minor axes.

**Unfortunately**, I don't think this figure is actually an ellipse, so my comment was incorrect.

Comment: Point taken. Do you have a method for taking solutions of $x,y$ and obtaining the major and minor axes? Or the eccentricity directly? I will take another look

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure I have a point, since the figure I drew above isn't an ellipse. Presumably, 'tilted ellipses' do exist and there are formulas for them, but I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: Well, the point I assumed that you were making, is that an intersection with a "tilted plane" with an "aligned" ellipse could yield such a figure, and the equation for eccentricity that I provided, actually doesn't yield the major axis.

Comment: OK, yes, that's the point I was making. However, I haven't been able to prove my point, so I'm no longer sure it's true.